# Why is my indexOf not showing any value other than -1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have a really basic array that shows variations of my name.

This is it right here..

```
var allTogether = ["Kenny", "Ken", "Ken", "kenny", "ken", "ken", "Kenny", "Ken", "Ken", "kenny", "ken", "ken", "Kenny", "Ken", "Ken"];
```

However, I tried a basic indexOf method for the array and this is the result.

```
allTogether.indexOf(4);
-1
```

Then I tried.

```
allTogether.indexOf('kenny');
-1
```

What's going on? I know that -1 means that the element has not been found but I'm missing some crucial information about this method entire.

Thanks in advance, guys. Really appreciate the feedback :)

Edit: Tried this thing out on jsfiddle and well.. it works. I can't honestly figure out why it doesn't work in chrome developer. Your guesses are as good as mine guys. That said, I do honestly appreciate the feedback. This community is grade A'! :D

Comment: `allTogether.indexOf('kenny')` [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/pdv6L61h/1/)

Comment: Your code should and does work: https://jsfiddle.net/nhc5o5ja/

Comment: Weird... it doesn't lol. It should be just fine, I agree. Shrugs. I'm doing this on chrome.developer in case anyone was wonder.

Comment: The code you've posted is not the code with the error. Please post the code with the error. We can't help you without it. If you run the exact lines you posted in the console, `allTogether.indexOf('kenny');` returns `3`

Comment: What does e.g. `JSON.stringify(allTogether)` say?

Comment: Check the edit everyone. Thanks to all that replied, you guys are awesome.

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome Dev Tools, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allTogether.indexOf(4);`
returns -1 because 4 doesn't exist in your array.

`allTogether.indexOf('kenny');`
should return 3.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=example